# php/mysql: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, pdo

I need to update the `mailcode` in the users database. I created this code.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
$result = $statement->execute(array('email' => $email));
$user = $statement->fetch();

$mailcode = random_string();
$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET mailcode = :mailcode WHERE id = :userid");
$result = $statement->execute(array('mailcode' => sha1($mailcode), 'userid' => $user['id']));
```

I get this error below:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

I have written another PHP code using the same code snippets. It works in the other code, but it doesn't work in this code. I have tried many different spellings, but it still doesn't work.

This is the other code: This code snippet works in my code, while the other code doesn't.

```
$passwordcode = random_string();
$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET passwordcode = :passwordcode, passwordcode_time = NOW() WHERE id = :userid");
$result = $statement->execute(array('passwordcode' => sha1($passwordcode), 'userid' => $user['id']));
```

Why doesn't the other code work?

I tried many different spellings, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You are certain that PDO message is coming from that update query?

Comment: I am very sure. If I remove this update query I no longer get the error.